# GWT + AppEngine - Chat widgets or library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, chat

I need to integrate a chat widget/library created in GWT and Google App Engine (GAE) in my website. I searched on google but all i found were some tutorials regarding XMPP API and Channel API (in GAE).

Is there a library with widgets that also provide the functionality (for example GWT widgets + App Engine's XMPP service)? Or do I have to build one  from scratch ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gwt+xmpp+widget

Comment: The fact is that I need to integrate a chat service to my website (developed using GWT and App Engine) and I'm searching for the best way to do it.

Comment: I want the client to use the chat within my website, and because users can connect with OpenID (for ex. a yahoo address), I don't know if the XMPP service is enough.

Comment: did you find anything?? I am also looking for exactly  the same thing.

Comment: I did not find an already built system, but I believe I could build one myself - using the AppEngine's XMPP API, I believe it is possible to create a temporary ID for those that do not use GMail... or something like that. But my last research was a few months ago, so maybe there's something new out there...